# How do CSS custom properties cascade?

Tags: html, css, css-variables

Let's say I have following CSS :

```
:root { --color: blue; }
div { --color: green; }
#alert { --color: red; }
* { color: var(--color); }
```

and my markup is :

```
<p>I inherited blue from the root element!</p>
<div>I got green set directly on me!</div>
<div id="alert">
  While I got red set directly on me!
  <p>I’m red too, because of inheritance!</p>
</div>
```

My question is Does the CSS above translate to :

```
body {
  color: blue;
}
div {
  color: green;
}
#alert{
  color: red;
}
```

or is there an additional

```
* {
  color: red;
}
```

Without variables the universal selector applies the same CSS on all elements. Does this change and the styling becomes dependent on elements?

One more question I have is if `:root` translates to `body` in CSS.

Here is a CodePen demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrvLJQ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've correctly stated in your title, custom properties *cascade*. In fact, this is why the module is called *CSS Custom Properties for Cascading Variables*. That means your custom property `--color` is evaluated as-is per element, just as with any other CSS property. In terms of the actual styles that are applied to your elements, what you really only have is:

```
* {
  color: var(--color);
}
```

The `var(--color)` value is then evaluated for each element based on how the `--color` property cascades. So it follows that:

- The `body` element has a blue foreground.
- Any `div` elements have a green foreground.
- The element whose ID is "alert" has a red foreground.
- Because you don't have a `--color` definition for `*`, it's [inherited](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#defining-variables) by default. Therefore all other elements inherit `--color` from their parent element: `body > p` inherits from `body`, becoming blue, and `#alert > p` inherits from `#alert`, becoming red.

If you really do want to express the cascaded values in terms of CSS, you could say that it translates to the following:

```
:root {
  color: blue;
}
div {
  color: green;
}
#alert {
  color: red;
}
* {
  color: inherit;
}
```

But *only* because the original CSS contains an explicit `* { color: var(--color); }` definition which ensures that every element's `color` maps to `--color`.

Note also that the code that you have comes from [an example within the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#example-f8770692), which itself is described as follows:

> If a custom property is declared multiple times, the standard cascade rules help resolve it. Variables always draw from the computed value of the associated custom property on the same element

---

> One more question I have is if `:root` translates to `body` in CSS.

1. `:root` doesn't translate to any element in CSS, because CSS is document language-agnostic.
2. `:root` doesn't translate to `body` in HTML; it corresponds to `html`.